# Roman Numerals in Java

Tags: java, converting, roman-numerals

I wrote a class that can convert *to and fro* from **Roman Numerals** and **Decimals**. I would appreciate critical points on *everything*, especially:

1. Shortening my code.
2. Choosing a better approach.
3. Using better/new features of Java 8.

And so on...

I didn't add JavaDoc because I am expecting suggestions for a *better approach*. I will document it then. Here is the class:

### `RomanNumeral.java`

```
package library.util;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A "recreational" class that provides that functionality of converting
 * values to and fro from Roman numerals.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 */
public class RomanNumeral {

    private final String representation;
    private final int value;

    private RomanNumeral(String representation, int value) {
        this.representation = representation;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return representation;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static RomanNumeral of(String representation) throws
            NumberFormatException,
            ArithmeticException {
        // Zero wasn't supported then...
        if (representation.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Empty String.");
        }
        int value = 0, previous = 0;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(representation);
        builder.reverse();  // go in the opposite manner
        for (int i = 0; i < builder.length(); i++) {
            try {
                int current = map.get(String.valueOf(builder.charAt(i)));
                // If the value suddenly drops then subtract, don't add.
                value += current < previous ? -current : current;
                previous = current;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // A NullPointerException will be thrown only if the
                // character is not present in the map.
                throw new NumberFormatException
                        ("Unrecognised character : " + builder.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        // calling representationOf() makes sure that "IIIII" becomes "V".
        return new RomanNumeral(representationOf(value), value);
    }

    public static RomanNumeral valued(int value) {
        return new RomanNumeral(representationOf(value), value);
    }

    public static String representationOf(int value)
            throws ArithmeticException {
        // The valid range is (0, 5000)
        if (value <= 0 || value >= 5_000) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Unsupported value : " + value);
        }
        int copy = value;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(10);  // 4999 gives 10 chars
        // The descending order is maintained
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            int v = entry.getValue();
            String k = entry.getKey();
            while (copy >= v) {
                copy -= v;
                builder.append(k);
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private static final Map<String, Integer> map;

    static {
        // Using LikedHashMap ensures retention of order.
        Map<String, Integer> temporary = new LinkedHashMap<>(13);
        // Initialize in descending order.
        temporary.put("M", 1_000);
        temporary.put("CM", 900);
        temporary.put("D", 500);
        temporary.put("CD", 400);
        temporary.put("C", 100);
        temporary.put("XC", 90);
        temporary.put("L", 50);
        temporary.put("XL", 40);
        temporary.put("X", 10);
        temporary.put("IX", 9);
        temporary.put("V", 5);
        temporary.put("IV", 4);
        temporary.put("I", 1);
        // Make an unmodifiable map out of it .
        map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(temporary);
    }

}
```

The algorithm for converting from Roman to Decimal is adapted from [this post](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/01/project-euler-89-converting-to-and-from.html).

Answer (score 5):

I like that you use an immutable map.  However I don't like the name `map`: you should give it a more descriptive name and it should be capitalized since it is a constant.  You should also declare the type of `map` as `LinkedHashMap`: it is important here since you do use the ordering property.  You can define `map` as `private static final Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>() {{ this.put(x, y); ... }}`.

Your api should probably return an error on invalid roman numeral instead of: `// calling representationOf() makes sure that "IIIII" becomes "V".`

In method `of` (string to int), I think you don't have to use a `StringBuilder` and to invert it.  You can easily modify your algorithm to work forward and just use `toCharArray`.  You could use the Java 8 "functional" (Stream) features here instead of a for-loop.  I like functional programming since it makes for shorter and more readable code, but they really messed things up in Java 8 and I couldn't find an easy solution.  I could do it in Scala, but in Java 8 it would end up being longer than your code and completely unreadable.

Comment: I like your answer, especially the part about the naming and the types. But I would appreciate if you provided some code to substantiate your claim about the representation method.

Comment: The problem with a functional approach is, that dismantling the number into it's parts is inherently mutating the value you work on. As such a functional solution is bound to be clunky.